# Can a inscribed triangle divide a circle into 4 integer parts?

Tags: geometry

##### Question

Draw an inscribed triangle on a circle and divide the circle into four parts $A, B, C, D$.

Can the areas of these parts be integers?

[image]

##### My attempt

Find the area of the arc from the central angle $(\alpha, \beta, \theta)$

$$
\begin{aligned}
S &= π r^2\\
A &= \frac{r^2}{2}(\alpha-\sin\alpha)\\
B &= \frac{r^2}{2}(\beta-\sin\beta)\\
C &= \frac{r^2}{2}(\gamma-\sin\gamma)\\
\end{aligned}
$$

with constraints

$$
\begin{aligned}
S &= A+B+C+D\\
2π &= \alpha + \beta + \gamma\\
\end{aligned}
$$

which can expand to

$$
π r^2 = \frac{r^2}{2}(\alpha-\sin\alpha) + \frac{r^2}{2}(\beta-\sin\beta)+\frac{r^2}{2}(2π - \alpha - \beta-\sin(2π - \alpha - \beta))+D
$$

and then simplify as

$$
D=\frac{r^2}{2}(4 \pi -2 (\alpha +\beta )+\sin (\alpha +\beta )+\sin (\alpha )+\sin (\beta ))
$$

so, for $\pi>\beta \geqslant \alpha > 0$, $r\in\mathbb{R}_+$ have relation

$$
\begin{aligned}
A &= \frac{r^2}{2}(\alpha-\sin\alpha)\\
B &= \frac{r^2}{2}(\beta-\sin\beta)\\
C &= \frac{r^2}{2}(2 \pi - (\alpha +\beta )+\sin(\alpha +\beta)\\
D &=\frac{r^2}{2}(4 \pi -2 (\alpha +\beta )+\sin (\alpha +\beta )+\sin (\alpha )+\sin (\beta ))\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Looks like both have the form $p\pi - q$, if 4-parts are all rational numbers after removing this common factor, then you can adjust $r$ to make the four parts are integers.

I don't know how to find a integer solution or explain no solution.

Comment: The drawing has $\gamma$ and you wrote $\theta$

Comment: sorry, typo mistake

Comment: Since $A+B+C+D=\pi r^2$ is required to be rational, I think the question reduces to the simultaneous rationality of $r^2(\alpha-\sin\alpha)$, $r^2(\beta-\sin\beta)$, and $r^2(\alpha+\beta-\sin(\alpha+\beta))$.

Comment: Note you can rephrase the question in the unit disk, asking for a triangle with the ratios rational. You get that you need such a triangle with the areas all rational multiples of $\pi.$

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4317354/inscribe-a-triangle-in-a-circle-to-produce-four-areas-can-the-four-areas-be-int?noredirect=1#comment9465974_4317354).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, just some thoughts.

Note you can rephrase the question in the unit disk, asking for a triangle with the ratios of the areas rational. If such a triangle exists, you can  scale the circle and triangle to get integer areas, and visa verso.

In the unit disk, you get that the areas must be rational multiples of $\pi.$

If $f(x)=x-\sin x,$ this means you need $\alpha,\beta$ with $f(\alpha),f(\beta),f(\alpha+\beta)$ all rational multiples of $\pi.$

There are, of course, the degenerate case where $\alpha=\beta=\pi,$ or more generally, when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are integer multiples of $\pi.$

Unfortunately, the $f$ is difficult to characterize in terms of number theory. Specifically, the set $S=f^{-1}(\pi\mathbb Q)$ is difficult to characterize. Certainly, $S$ doesn’t  include any rational multiples of $\pi,$ other than the integer multiples of $\pi,$ the degenerate cases.

If you can’t find a nice property of $f,$ there is certainly no reason to expect to find non-degenerate angles with $\alpha,\beta,\alpha+\beta\in S,$ since $S$ is countable.